# I deal only with those close to me

Tags: riddle

> I am overjoyed when I get held up in traffic
>
> I drive to get my coffee at lunch
>
> But never to work in the morning
>
> Once I enter my office
>
> I disappear

Comment: I do know some colleagues who disappear once they enter office :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you a

> Taxi or limo Driver?

am overjoyed when I get held up in traffic

> Money, money, money!

I drive to get my coffee at lunch

> Yep!

But never to work in the morning

> I walk to the car

Once I enter my office
I disappear

> I drive off anyway... and maybe I have black out windows and one of those role up screens?

Comment: Yup! Well done! Nice addition about the blackout windows :)